# PFLogInViewController issue

Tags: ios, parse-platform, pfloginviewcontroller

I am trying to compile an iOS app that has been on the appStore for a while, in other words an app already running.

At this line of code:

```
@interface CustomLogInViewController : PFLogInViewController
```

I get an error saying:

```
Cannot find interface declaration for PFLogInViewController
```

I have recently downloaded the last version (parse-library-1.6.2) of the Parse SDK.
Could that be the cause?

I have checked the Parse.h (and other .h files) file contents and indeed it does not contain PFLogInViewController. It seems that older versions were different.

In an older SDK I can see under
Parse.framework/Versions/A/Headers
a file called Parse.h containing a line:

```
#import <Parse/PFLogInViewController.h>
```

Does anyone see what I am missing here?

Comment: have you included <Parse/parse.h> in your header file?

Comment: As I mentioned the app was already running, so the following line is present:
#import <Parse/Parse.h>
And there is no message to signal a missing header file.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the solution I found.

Replacing:

```
#import <Parse/Parse.h>
```

by:

```
#import <Parse/Parse.h>
#import <ParseUI/ParseUI.h>
```

and the problem is gone.